# AWS CodeArtifact - separate repositories for test and production environments

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, aws-codeartifact

We recently built a core JPA layer application that we manage on AWS CodeArtifact.  We have multiple applications that consume this jar.  No problem there.  Management wants separate repositories for test and production.  But upon research using phind (chat GPT) states that

> "When using AWS CodeArtifact to share a jar across multiple
> applications, it is generally recommended to use the same repository
> for both test and production."

I was inclined to think the same way, but management wants them separated.

Our applications are maven/spring boot.  The repositories and other AWS config stuff are configured in settings.xml.  I would be switching between repos depending on the `spring.profiles.active` property.

First, would like the opinions on which way to go and/or any sample code for your configuration.

Comment: What is the reason behind wanting separate repositories? Generally it sounds a bit strange to me since the common approach is to externalize configuration from the application to make it possible to deploy in multiple environments.

Comment: The reasoning I'm being given is possibility over overwriting the jar file prod points to.  I don't know if that's even possible with code artifact.  I guess it's entirely 'possible', but in any case we have a build script that automatically creates the next sequence of the jar version so it's not likely.  Yes, 'separate repository' might be the wrong way to go about it.  I have used UDeploy in an enterprise environment.  But I didn't set that up.  Right now I'm just looking for a quick and dirty solution to separate deployment to diff environments.

Answer (score 0):

Was able to solve this by doing this in pom.xml:

```
<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>backend-prod</id>
        <name>Production Repository</name>
        <url>https://mydomain-XXXXXXXXXXXX.d.codeartifact.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/maven/backend-prod/</url>
    </repository>
    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>backend-test</id>
        <name>Test Repository</name>
        <url>https://mydomain-XXXXXXXXXXXX.d.codeartifact.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/maven/backend-test/</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
</distributionManagement>
```

With the above, maven will look for a version with -SNAPSHOT appended.  So in our build bash script, we are already checking for ENV, which is either 'test' or 'prod'.  If test, then we append -SNAPSHOT to the version and maven handles the rest - uploading the artifact to the snapshotRepository